# Overriding ArrayAdapter in Android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, overriding

While overriding ArrayAdapter to a custom adapter (FancyAdapter) I've got errors like Undefined getLayoutInflater(). Plus in constructor of custom adapter (FancyAdapter) class code super ( MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, noteList ); getting error in "MainActivity.this" and "noteList" that they are inaccessible. My Code is as follow:
-----MainActivity.java-----

```
package my.android.notelist;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewStub;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList <String> noteList = new ArrayList<String> ( );
FancyAdapter aa = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final EditText txtTodo = ( EditText ) findViewById ( R.id.txtTodo );
    Button btAdd = ( Button ) findViewById ( R.id.btnAdd );
    ListView lvList = ( ListView ) findViewById ( R.id.lvList );

    aa = new FancyAdapter( );

    lvList.setAdapter( aa );

    btAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {           
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            noteList.add( txtTodo.getText().toString());
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
            txtTodo.setText("");
        }
    });
    }
}

class FancyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
public FancyAdapter ( )
{
    super ( MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, noteList );
}

public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent )
{
    View row = convertView;

    if ( row == null )
    {
        final LayoutInflater inflater =  getLayoutInflater ( );
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);

        ( ( TextView ) row.findViewById(R.id.noteText)).setText ( noteList.get(position));
        return (row);
    }
    }
}
```

-----main.xml-----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtTodo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Item" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

-------custom_list_item.xml-------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/noteText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution,

I didnt implemented FancyAdapter class inside the MainActivity class. As I did that all the errors gone...

Thanks :-)